# Issue when trying to run Visual Studio Windows Mobile emulator

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have getting the following error message when trying to start the windows mobile emulator from within visual studio:
[image]

I have had a look around the web for a solution but nothing seems to be standing out...
the Specs for the PC are:
7.5 GB Memory
4 processors (2 core)
Windows 10

Help would be greatly appreciated with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Hyper-V in Windows AND BIOS? This is usually required:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Did you try to configure where the drive is supposed to be? The error message does say that your C-drive does not support hard disk sharing